# Multidimensional array of name value pairs randomly to display questions (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm new to multidimensional arrays and using objects like this to display data. What I'm trying to achieve is to loop through and randomly display a question within the array and then the user will type the answer "higher, or lower" and match the input value to the answer object.

Currently I'm just displaying "0" as my output. I assume this has to do with the questions.length part as only being one array since the opening bracket consists of objects?

How can I achieve a random question generation?

If I need to further explain please let me know but it should just be a simple ask a question and compare the value of the users input to the answer and display correct or incorrect.

```js
$(function() {

function gameStart(){ 
 var questions = [
  {  
   question1: {
    question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $40.00?', 
    answer: 'higher'
   },
   question2: {
    question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $100.00?', 
    answer: 'higher'
   },
   question3: {
    question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $50.00?', 
    answer: 'lower'
   }
  }
 ];

 var i;
 for(i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*questions.length);
 }
}
gameStart();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2 id="question"></h2>
</div>
 <label for="text">Answer:</label>
 <input id="user-answer" type="text" value="">
 <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

 <p id="sorry" style="display: none">Sorry...</p>
 <p id="correct" style="display: none">You got it!</p>
```

Comment: If you want to select a random question, you will not loop over the questions.  You want to generate a random number between [0, array length - 1], once.  And then that points to the question to use.

Comment: You don't have a multidimensional array. You have an array containing an object. The array length is 1.

Comment: However your data model makes this slightly odd.  You have an array with a single object in it, which has keys for the different questions.  It would be easier if this array just contained the question objects.

Comment: @matt, perhaps I don't understand how to structure a multidimensional array. But yes I can see that the array contains 1 object. But then within that object I have more objects, right?

Comment: @taplar, so my array structure is incorrect? If the array contained only the question, how could I compare the users input to the correct answer?

Comment: @Nick0989 look at Luiz Carlos answer below.  They've converted your questions into the array structure I would suggest.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here' a working version of your game. Here are some advice:

1. **structure of the code**:

   1. change your data structure from

      ```
      [{ question1: {...}, question2: {...}, question3: {...} }]
      ```

      to

      ```
      [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]
      ```

      This way it will be easier to access the array and the keys are not redundant.
   2. put the object `questions` containing the q&a **outside** the function because it doesn't belong in the logic of your game. You can think of it as external data.
   3. separate your code in functions, here we'll have `askQuestion` which will check for the input and display the success/failure message ; and `randomQuestion` which will get a random question from the `questions` and print it on the screen.
2. We will use an **event listener** with `addEventListener` linked to the button:

   ```
   document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', askQuestion)
   ```

   This will trigger the function `askQuestion` every time the button is clicked.
3. **About `askQuestion`**:

   The user has either entered the correct answer or not. If the former another question is displayed with `randomQuestion` and *success* message appears, if the latter a *failure* message appears. If the question has changed `answer` will be updated.
4. **About `randomQuestion`**:

   1. The following will take a random element from the `questions` array:

      ```
      questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)]
      ```
   2. clean up the input box by adding an empty string:

      ```
      document.querySelector('#user-answer').value = '';
      ```
   3. Create an element with `document.createElement`, add the actual question to the element, remove the previous question and append the new question element to `#question`:

      ```
      const element = document.createElement('div');
      element.innerHTML = question.question;

      document.querySelector('#question').firstChild.remove();
      document.querySelector('#question').appendChild(element.firstChild);
      ```
   4. return the answer

      ```
      return question.answer;
      ```

---

Here is the full JavaScript code:

```
document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', askQuestion)

const questions = [{
    question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $40.00?',
    answer: 'higher'
  },
  {
    question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $100.00?',
    answer: 'higher'
  },
  {
    question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $50.00?',
    answer: 'lower'
  }
];

function askQuestion() {
  if(answer && document.querySelector('#user-answer').value == answer) {
    document.querySelector('#correct').style.display  = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#sorry').style.display = 'none';
    answer = randomQuestion()
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#correct').style.display  = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#sorry').style.display = 'block';
  }
}


function randomQuestion() {
  const question = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];

  document.querySelector('#user-answer').value = '';

  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.innerHTML = question.question;

  document.querySelector('#question').firstChild.remove();
  document.querySelector('#question').appendChild(element.firstChild);

  return question.answer;
}

let answer = randomQuestion();
```

```js
document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', askQuestion)

const questions = [{
    question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $40.00?',
    answer: 'higher'
  },
  {
    question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $100.00?',
    answer: 'higher'
  },
  {
    question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $50.00?',
    answer: 'lower'
  }
];

function askQuestion() {
  if (answer && document.querySelector('#user-answer').value == answer) {
    document.querySelector('#correct').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#sorry').style.display = 'none';
    answer = randomQuestion()
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#correct').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#sorry').style.display = 'block';
  }
}


function randomQuestion() {
  const question = questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];

  document.querySelector('#user-answer').value = '';

  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.innerHTML = question.question;

  document.querySelector('#question').firstChild.remove();
  document.querySelector('#question').appendChild(element.firstChild);

  return question.answer;
}

let answer = randomQuestion();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <h2 id="question"><span></span></h2>
</div>
<label for="text">Answer:</label>
<input id="user-answer" type="text" value="">
<button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

<p id="sorry" style="display: none">Sorry...</p>
<p id="correct" style="display: none">You got it!</p>
```

Comment: Awesome I will review this! I have been trying to figure out how to code this game for months honestly. Where did you learn JS? I've used Lynda, treehouse, code academy, and I still suck lol.

Comment: Here it is, I've added all the necessary information. Honestly, JavaScript comes with some practice. No I have never taken courses to learn JS. Practice practice, practice!

Comment: Above and beyond man! Thank you so much. I've built a lot of javascript interactives within web pages but never a game so this is really helpful.

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 5):

First of all I would change your object structure:

```
var questions = [
    {
        question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $40.00?', 
        answer: 'higher'
    },
    {
        question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $100.00?', 
        answer: 'higher'
    },
     {
        question: 'Is the price higher or lower than $50.00?', 
        answer: 'lower'
    }
];
```

Once you change to this structure you'll be able to access the questions by using your previous code: `var index = Math.floor(Math.random()*questions.length)`. This will return the index for your question. Now you can access the object like: `questions[index].question` or `question[index].answer`.